# multi-core configuration awareness in play framework

Tags: playframework

I'm new to multi-core configuration. What configuration should be done for efficient use of play-1.2.3 multi-core implementation in play! framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play team recommends to set the thread pool to nb proc + 1 for prod.
I have 2 proc so my config will be:

```
# Execution pool
# ~~~~~
# Default to 1 thread in DEV mode or (nb processors + 1) threads in PROD mode.
# Try to keep a low as possible. 1 thread will serialize all requests (very useful for debugging purpose)
play.pool=1
%prod.play.pool=3
%prod1.play.pool=3
```

I think one of the most important point is to keep your controllers very fast otherwise they will block your http threads. So if you have heavy duty operations use [play asynchronous](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous) capabilities and make use of the cache.

Remember that play is stateless too which limits the concurrency issues.

Comment: Is this setting something only supported if we use play server? Or will this work even if we deploy play app as a war to tomcat?

Comment: Since the application will not use the internal netty web server and serve the requests itself, I don't think this would make a difference when deployed as a war.